# Undefined reference to both Conctructor and destructor

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to write unit test usig `google test` and `google mock` but I have little difficulties with that. I'm getting error ( which You can see below) I can't fix.

```
DummyUT.o: In function `~MockApplicationClass':
srctest/../mocks/AppMock.h:15: undefined reference to `Application::~Application()'
srctest/../mocks/AppMock.h:15: undefined reference to `Application::~Application()'
DummyUT.o: In function `MockApplicationClass':
srctest/../mocks/AppMock.h:15: undefined reference to `Application::Application()'
srctest/../mocks/AppMock.h:15: undefined reference to `Application::~Application()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [TestApp] Error 1
```

Here my AppMock.h file:

```
#ifndef APPMOCK_H_
#define APPMOCK_H_
#include "../../app.hxx"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
class MockApplicationClass: public Application
{
  public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD2(Reset, void(int i, const char* chr));
};
#endif /* APPMOCK_H_ */
```

here app.hxx file:

```
class Application {
   public:
      Application();
      ~Application();
      int Reset(int i, const char* chr)
}
```

Conctructor and destructor are defined in file app.cxx. Destructor is trivial:

```
//Deconstruction method
Application::~Application() {
    // release all resources before exit

} // end of ~Application()
```

DummyUT file:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "../DummyClass.h" //path to code being tested
#include "../../app.hxx"
#include "../../testClass.h"
#include "../mocks/dummyMock.h" //path to mock
#include "../mocks/AppMock.h"
#include "../mocks/testMock.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

using ::testing::AllOf;
using ::testing::Ge;
using ::testing::Le;

TEST(Test, testaplikacji)
{
    const char* a="abc";
    MockApplicationClass theClass;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

And Make file:

```
CXX=g++

GTEST_DIR = ../../../UTframework/gmock-1.7.0/gtest
GMOCK_DIR = ../../../UTframework/gmock-1.7.0/


EXXX_PATH_PRE = /home/XXX/dev/exxx

# flags
CPPFLAGS += -isystem $(GTEST_DIR)/include -isystem $(GMOCK_DIR)/include 
CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread
GMOCK_LIB = $(GMOCK_DIR)/make
# All tests produced by this Makefile.  Remember to add new tests you
TESTS = TestApp

CPPFLAGS += -isystem /home/XXX/dev/exxx/target/dataserver/include
CPPFLAGS += -isystem ../../Conflib/include
CPPFLAGS += -isystem /home/XXX/dev/exxx/target/XX/include
# All Google Test headers.  Usually you shouldn't change this
# definition.
GTEST_HEADERS = $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/*.h \
    $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/internal/*.h

# All Google Mock headers. Note that all Google Test headers are
# included here too, as they are #included by Google Mock headers.
# Usually you shouldn't change this definition.
GMOCK_HEADERS = $(GMOCK_DIR)/include/gmock/*.h \
    $(GMOCK_DIR)/include/gmock/internal/*.h \
    $(GTEST_HEADERS)

all: $(TESTS)

clean:
rm -f $(TESTS) *.o

TestCIPApp: DummyUT.o DummyClass.o testClass.o
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)  $^ -L$(GMOCK_LIB) -lgmock_main -o $@

DummyUT.o: srctest/DummyUT.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

DummyClass.o:   DummyClass.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
copy:
    cp $(TESTS) ../../../UTBuildAll
```

Comment: It looks like you're not compiling and linking `app.cxx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before you have to add another target for App:

```
app.o:   app.cpp
```

And TestCIPApp must depends on this:

```
TestCIPApp: DummyUT.o DummyClass.o testClass.o app.o
```

Now the objectfile is also there and the symbols can be found.